# Splitting Unix command for use with exec

Tags: c, unix, exec, ansi-c

I have a program which takes command from input, and then executes it using `execl` (it has to be function from `execvp` family). Right now, assuming the input line is `in` , can I simply use `execl(allBeforeFirstSpaceFromIn, in);` , or do I have to divide `in` into smaller strings? If so, can I simply change all white spaces to `\0`?

Comment: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant. You probably mean the null character, `'\0'`.

Comment: Yep, sorry for that :)

Comment: If you already read my answer, read it again; I've updated it several times in the last few minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So your input is a single string, something like:

```
"/bin/cat file1 file2"
```

No, you can't just pass `"/bin/cat"` as one argument to `execl`, and `"file1 file2"` as another argument. That would cause `/bin/cat` to attempt to open a file named `file1 file2`. You want it to open two files, `file1` and `file2`, which means you need to pass three separate arguments.

`execl` probably isn't suitable for what you're doing. It's a variadic function; to call it, you have to know *when you write your code* how many arguments you want to pass to it. So this:

```
execl("/bin/cat", "file1", "file2");
```

should work, but you can't build that call from a string.

You want to use one of the `execv*()` functions instead. For example:

```
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
```

The `argv` argument is a pointer-to-pointer-to-char, which should point to the first element of an array of `char*` elements, each of which points to the first character of a `'\0'`-terminated string.

So you'll have to build that array of pointers, and initialize each one to point to a string argument.

Now if you have an array containing the string:

```
"/bin/cat file1 file2"
```

one approach would be to replace the spaces with null characters:

```
"/bin/cat\0file1\0file2\0"
```

(that last `\0` was already there).  You could then construct your array of `char*` so that each element points either to the beginning of the array, or just after one of the `'\0'` characters you just created.  Each such pointer is a valid pointer to a string.

But I wouldn't necessarily recommend that approach. You're going to run into problems if your input string happens to contain multiple spaces between words (which you'll probably want to treat as single spaces), or if you want to do something fancy like expanding wildcards. I suggest just allocating the arrays yourself and copying the appropriate data into them. The space you save by re-using your input string isn't worth the effort.

Of course the simplest approach is:

```
char command[] = "/bin/cat file1 file2";
system(command);
exit(0);
```

which passes the command string to `/bin/sh`, which does all that work for you. But then you wouldn't be learning how to use the `exec*()` functions, which I presume is the point of this exercise.

Comment: What if the command contains `"`, like in `/bin/echo "Hello World"`? It would be split to `/bin/echo`, `"Hello` and `World"`.

Comment: @DavidCzihak: Yes, it would -- and whether that's the right thing to do depends on your requirements. Shells typically *don't* just split command lines on whitespace; `echo "hello world"` passes a single argument `hello world` (including the space but not including the quotes) to the `echo` command. But I think that's more than the OP is trying to deal with for now.

Comment: Maybe, but I think possible pitfalls should be pointed out no matter how obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to pass arguments as separate strings.

For `execlX` functions you need to pass each argument as an argument:

```
execl(prog, arg1, arg2,...);
```

For `execvX` functions you need to pass an array of c-style strings:

```
char **argv = /* ... */;
argv[0] = "arg1";
argv[1] = "arg2";
execv(prog, args);
```

To split the input string you can use `strtok`, or just do something like:

```
char **argv = /* malloc stuff */;
char *prev = in;
cnt = 0;
while (in[0]) {
  if (in[0] == ' ') {
    in[0] = 0;
    argv[cnt++] = prev;
    prev = in + 1;
  }
  in++;
}
argv[cnt++] = prev;
argv[cnt]   = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to call *exec*, either provide all arguments one by one (*execl*) or provide an array of arguments (*execv*).

If you provide a long string having all arguments separated with `\0` *exec* will not understand that other arguments exist after the first one.

So you have either to

- use *execl* and provide a list of arguments, eg (..., in, in+x, in+y, NULL)
- or make an array of `(char *)` strings each of the elements pointing to `in`, `in+x`, `in+y`, ..., and use *execv*

with `x` and `y` (...) being the index in the long string of the arguments, e.g. `in` being

```
command\0arg1\0arg2\0
^0       ^8    ^13
```

`x` would be 8 and `y` would be 13. And you could create an array of strings

```
char *args[] = { in, in+x, in+y, NULL };
```

then use *execv* `execv(in, args);`

Comment: In fact a "long string having all arguments separated with `\0`" isn't a string, which is by definition terminated by the first `'\0'` character. For example, any function expecting a pointer to a string, if you pass it `"echo\0hello\0world"` will only see the `"echo"`. (Which is basically what you said.)